# Regex to replace everything before last forward slash

Tags: regex, string

I'm doing some string manipulation and I'm very bad at regular expression. I have some string like:

```
/sonata-economy-analog-watch-men/p/itmda5wagvmtttwr
```

I want to replace everything before the last forward slash by a blank and get only "itmda5wagvmtttwr". Does anyone know how to do this with regular expressions?

Updated -
Actually I'm doing this in xml.

```
        let $url :=data($item//a[@class="fk-anchor-link"]/@href)
        let $temp :=fn:substring-before($url, "?")
    let $temp2 :=fn:replace()
```

In url I will get string as

```
/titan-htse-analog-watch-men/p/itmd9gjfprgdt8d8?pid=WATD9H76AMCWDYT5&amp;ref=28b766fc-2692-4ba3-a4cb-ea8a060cc9ec
```

And using fn:substring-before($url, "?") I have taken everything before ? and in temp I'm getting,

```
/titan-htse-analog-watch-men/p/itmd9gjfprgdt8d8
```

Now I want to replace everything before last "/" and get only "itmd9gjfprgdt8d8" in temp2

Comment: Split it with `/`, then take the last element.

Answer (score 1):

You could search for

```
[^/]*$
```

which gives you all non-slash characters adjacent to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `-after`-equivalent of `fn_substring-before`: http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_substring-after-last.html

```
let $temp :=fn:substring-after-last(fn:substring-before($url, "?"), "/")
```

No need for regex :)